# Error upon driver initialization: "Failed to start browser <...>\firefox.exe: other os error (SessionNotCreated)"

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

The program I am trying to make has an error that keeps displaying every time I try to run it. The error states that

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Failed to start browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe: other os error (SessionNotCreated)'

My Code is listed below and when my program runs the line it is the line with `IwebDriver driver = new Firefox();`

I do not have a Program Files (x86)\Mozilla firefox folder
I do have a Programs Files\Mozilla firefox folder

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
//using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

//Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver -Version 3.14.0 


FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Users\Jay_J\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64", "geckodriver.exe");
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

Also I get this as my console screen output

> 1539119672765   mozrunner::runner INFO Running command: "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile""C:\Users\Jay_J\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.70e1pqkzBcHh"

I have tried other ways to use the service and the Webdriver portion of my code. Do I need to have firefox in x86 for programs??? I do not have it, but I guess I can download another version of FireFox which would be a large pain for me. However I don't know what to do. Is there a way to be able to run selenium on my machine?

My Stack Trace Shows:

[This IS the Stack Trace for my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNZ9A.png)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.